# Can I use LINQ to lists in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, linq

Can I use LINQ with lists in sharepoint online? If so, can someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in SharePoint online

> SharePoint 2010 includes the LINQ to SharePoint provider, which
>   translates LINQ statements to CAML queries. LINQ is a standard query
>   language and, when applied to SharePoint, it enables developers to
>   query SharePoint lists without requiring them to learn the CAML syntax
>   that is used internally by SharePoint.

Source:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17069

Comment: Yes, I've read the developer guide. I also tried spmetal, but as expected it did not work. I can't figure out how to write the query. Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Here is an example from the ms forums: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/35c5316f-379f-424c-b03a-0e09b94a4ad5/

Comment: Thanks a lot, to the both of you. So far, I have tried the following: Create a site locally in my sharepoint 2010 developement environment. Use SPMetal to generate the entities from the lists. Export the lists and the webpart to my sharepoint online site.
I  was able to get it up and running, but I had to change something in my javascript. After deploying the webpart for the second time, I got the errormessage about running in a sandboxed solution

Comment: Could you post the error log/message in your above post?

Comment: FreeStyler, there's not alot of details in the errormessage, I forgot it and have been unable to reproduce. Anyway, I managed to run my webpart now. As mentioned, I used SPMetal to generate entities from the list in my local sharepoint developement environment. I then created the same lists in sharepoint online in a new site, and added the visual webpart solution to sharepoint online. I was hoping I could just export my local site as a solution (with webpart included), and import it into my sharepoint online site. But all attempts have failed, giving me a varierity of errormessages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can use LINQ in SharePoint Online. I used it in a Visual web part which stores the information from the form to the list. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Create a ListContext File with the help of SPMetal
2. Now use the ListCotext file as the entity layer for the data saving and modification functionality